# How do you open your inventory in Undertale?

Tags: undertale

How do you open the inventory menu in Undertale?

Answer (score 8):

While playing Undertale, you'll want to use <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to open your menu and <kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select `Inventory`.

When you start up the game, the title screen features an [option menu where you can reconfigure your keys](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Joystick_Config). (or test the game with a joystick/gamepad if you want to use something other than a keyboard.)

In your case, it sounds like the controls might have been reconfigured at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are playing on Switch, hit "X."

Answer (score -3):

You just press C, but if you play one-handed, then you can use ctrl. But when you start the game, you can change this is you want to.

Comment: This adds nothing that the other answer didn't already say.